# How to measure graphic performance of Mac app?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-animation

In an iOS Xcode app, you can use the Core Animation Instrument to measure graphics performance issues such like laggy UITableView scrolling.  I want to do the same on the Mac for some layer backed views I am debugging.  In particular I would like to measure frame rate.  Any ideas how to do this since the Core Animation instrument isn't available for Mac apps?

Answer (score 1):

Frame Meter is available within "Quartz Debug"

- Menu Xcode > Open Developer Tool > More Developer Tools …
- Will open developer.apple.com and you'll have to sign in
- Download "Graphics Tools for Xcode - January 2013"
- Then use "Quartz Debug" for a Frame Meter

Comment: Did it work? Then you could add some details on how you did it and eventually mark the question as answered.